# javascript ajax returned value "stolen" in browser console

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser

I've got following javascript code that I execute in the browser:

```
function run(request) {
    var res;
    $.ajax({
      url:'http://custom-host:8080/',
      type: "POST",
      async: false,
      data: request
    }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
      console.log(textStatus);
      res = data;
    });
    return res;
}
```

It just asks my custom server for a response that it gets. The Chrome Console log looks like this:

```
> var a = run({command:'version'}); // executing custom function
success dev.pycached-admin/:14 // this is the console log
undefined // this is the console returned value
> a // ask for value a
"1.1" // value a (returned from ajax)
```

The question is: how come undefined is returned in the console, when actual value of '1.1' is returned afterwards (the value is correctly assigned)?

If I add `debugger` statement inside the done function:

```
}).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
  console.log(textStatus);
  debugger;
  res = data;
});
```

then I can see Apple's code which probably maintains the chrome console (`VM` files in the script tab). Anyway, the AJAX call is synchronous, so why is the value not returned for the first time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...so why is the value not returned for the first time?

It is, but `var` is a statement, not an expression, and so it cannot have a result for the console to display. You can see this if you just do this:

```
> var a = "foo";
undefined
> a
"foo"
```

So just do this:

```
> var a
undefined
> a = run({command:'version'});
```

...which should give you:

```
success dev.pycached-admin/:14 // this is the console log
"1.1"
```

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right: `var x //
undefined //
x = run({command:'version'}); //
success dev.pycached-admin/:14 //
"1.1"`